tumble dryer light turns on by itself and flickers
I'm not sure if this is the right space to ask this.
We have a fairly old (~ 15 years) tumble dryer, all of a sudden it sometimes turns its light on by itself.
It then flickers for a few seconds, stops, and sometimes repeats this multiple times.
The dryer isn't turned on when this happens but connected to the power.
It's the only device we can observe this behavior.
There is a washing machine connected to same outlet just below the tumble dryer, which does just fine.
Like here: https://www.electricaltechnology.org/2023/02/difference-between-socket-outlet-receptacle.html
I read that power fluctuation may cause phenomena like this, but it seems to me that something is going on with the dryer since it's the only device affected.
Is this something I should be worried about?
And what might be the cause for only affecting this device?

Most likely you have a bad switch controlling the light.

the light is controlled by turning the dryer on/off. Which is done with a switch on the dryer.
You mean that switch?

If the light comes on when you open the dryer door, I would suspect that is the switch that has worn out, or need to be adjusted.  I don't believe there is any issues with the house wiring.
